# towers of hanoi recursion not working correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to do towers of hanoi with 7 disks using recursion for a school project, I'm not sure what the problem is but the output is completely wrong. I assume it has something to do with the moveDisk() function but I'm unable to find the issue. The number of moves is correct. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code and please leave a comment if you have any questions:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct Peg
{
    vector<int> peg;
    string name;
};

void loadDisk(int diskNum, vector<int> &startPeg)
{
assert(startPeg.size() == 0);
for (int i = diskNum; i > 0; i--)
{
    startPeg.push_back(i);
}
}

void printPeg(int diskNum, vector<int> peg, string name)
{
cout << name << endl;
assert(peg.size() >= 0);
if (peg.size() > 0)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < peg.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << peg[i];
    }
}
cout << endl << endl;
}

void moveDisk(vector<int> &startPeg, vector<int> &goalPeg)
{
if (goalPeg.size() == 0)
{
    int temp = startPeg.back();
    startPeg.pop_back();
    goalPeg.push_back(temp);
}
}

int hanoi(int diskNum, vector<int> &startPeg, vector<int> &goalPeg, vector<int> &tempPeg)
{
int count = 0;
if (diskNum == 0)
{
    moveDisk(startPeg, goalPeg);
}
else
{
    count = hanoi(diskNum - 1, startPeg, tempPeg, goalPeg);
    moveDisk(startPeg, goalPeg); 
    count++;
    count += hanoi(diskNum - 1, tempPeg, goalPeg, startPeg);
}
return count;
}



int main()
{
Peg startPeg, tempPeg, goalPeg;
startPeg.name = "Start";
tempPeg.name = "Temp";
goalPeg.name = "Goal";
int diskNum = 7;

loadDisk(diskNum, startPeg.peg);

cout << "Starting Conditions with three pegs: " << endl;

printPeg(diskNum, startPeg.peg, startPeg.name);
printPeg(diskNum, tempPeg.peg, tempPeg.name);
printPeg(diskNum, goalPeg.peg, goalPeg.name);

int moveCount = hanoi(diskNum, startPeg.peg, tempPeg.peg, goalPeg.peg);

cout << "End Conditions with three pegs: " << endl;

printPeg(diskNum, startPeg.peg, startPeg.name);
printPeg(diskNum, tempPeg.peg, tempPeg.name);
printPeg(diskNum, goalPeg.peg, goalPeg.name);

cout << moveCount << " total moves were taken." << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

and the current output is :
Starting Conditions with three pegs:
Start
7654321

Temp

Goal

End Conditions with three pegs:
Start
76543

Temp
2

Goal
1

127 total moves were taken.

Comment: Why `if (goalPeg.size() == 0)`? You're saying only move to the goal peg if it's size is zero? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: I think that’s where the problem is, but without that line then you end up trying to call .back() on an empty vector

Comment: I think, it should be `if (diskNum == 1)` to avoid that. Just thinking though, I haven't run your code. Makes sense, if you only have one disk to move, you just move it, no need for recursion.

Comment: I did try that and it has little effect, still not quite what I was looking for but thank you for the response

Comment: It should be ´if(startPeg.size() == 0)' to avoid the empty move, non ?

Comment: @TungLeThanh No.

Answer (score 0):

```
void moveDisk(vector<int> &startPeg, vector<int> &goalPeg)
{
    // if (goalPeg.size() == 0) better only do that if
    if(startPeg.size() > 0)
    {
        int temp = startPeg.back();  // would fail otherwise
        startPeg.pop_back();
        goalPeg.push_back(temp);
    }
}

int hanoi(int diskNum, vector<int> &startPeg, vector<int> &goalPeg, vector<int> &tempPeg)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (diskNum == 0)
    {
        // moveDisk(startPeg, goalPeg);  you want to do absolutely nothing
        //                               when there are no discs.
    }
    else
    {
        count = hanoi(diskNum - 1, startPeg, tempPeg, goalPeg);
        moveDisk(startPeg, goalPeg);
        count++;
        count += hanoi(diskNum - 1, tempPeg, goalPeg, startPeg);
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    // ... 
    // int moveCount = hanoi(diskNum, startPeg.peg, tempPeg.peg, goalPeg.peg);
    // folowing the paramter names of your hanoi() it should be:
    int moveCount = hanoi(diskNum, startPeg.peg, goalPeg.peg, tempPeg.peg);

    // ...    
}
```